# docx document corrupted when copied though OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I am working on a code to export CV profile data to a Word document, following a template.
I am using C# and OpenXML.

I load the template-file to a MemoryStream, then make a new WordprocessingDocument from that.

The problem occours when I save this document to a file.
The resulting document can't be opened in neither MS Word nor LibreOffice Writer, giving me a general input/output error.

So I diabled the code I am testing for inserting the data, meaning the document I create should be an exact copy of the template. But no. No diffrence.

I had a closer look at the files, and unpacked both the template and the generated file, and ran them though WinMerge.
The structure inside the files are quite diffrent from each other.

Relevant part of the source-code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //force Visual studio to display errors in english (damned localized default settings)
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        string pathData = "C:/Users/Lars Erik/Desktop/oppdrag fra synnes/oc-ny.json";
        string pathTemplate = "C:/Users/Lars Erik/Desktop/oppdrag fra synnes/test_template/test_template.docx";
        if (!File.Exists(pathData))
        {
            WriteLine("The path for the data is not valid. File not found. Path: " + pathData);
            //return;
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(pathTemplate))
        {
            WriteLine("The path for the template is not valid. File not found. Path: " + pathTemplate);
            //return;
        }

        //string rawData = File.ReadAllText(pathData);
        FileStream Stream = new FileStream(pathData, FileMode.Open);
        Byte[] templateRawdata = File.ReadAllBytes(pathTemplate);
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        outputStream.Write(templateRawdata, 0, templateRawdata.Length);

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Consultant));
        Consultant data = serializer.ReadObject(Stream) as Consultant;

        //JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        //Object data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawData);
        //Consultant data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Consultant>(rawData);

        //WriteLine(data.ToString());
        WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathTemplate, false);
        WordprocessingDocument outputdoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputStream, true);
        //TranslateCV(data, template, ref outputdoc);
        //outputdoc.Close();
        outputStream.CopyTo(File.Create("C:/Users/Lars Erik/Desktop/oppdrag fra synnes/OUTPUT/testresult.docx"));
    }
```

Here is some screenshots from WinMerge comparing the should-be identical template and resulting document:
[image: Root directory in each document. Notice left(template) has a file and folder right don't have]
[image: docProps]
[image: word]
*(The UI is in Norwegian. Not sure if I can change that)*

Comment: What do you need the MemoryStream for? There is an overload that uses a filename directly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562234(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I'm new to using OpenXML, and thought it was required. I shall rewrite to not use a memory stream, and see if it helps.

Comment: Huh? Well, look at that. The resulting file is not corrupted now.
Something must have gone wrong when running it though the MemoryStream. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you didn't reset Position on the Stream. But that's only a suspicion.